# Is there anyway to execute a web scoped timer jobs manually

Tags: 2007, development, timer-jobs, staging

My timer job runs every 15 minutes so on Staging server I have to wait 15 minutes while waiting for results after deploying it, is there any way I can simply execute it, I remember there was some STSADM command that executes some timer jobs but not sure if that is what am supposed to try.

STSADM command  `

stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs`

I don't think if it will execute my custom timer job as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command is correct, but you need to make sure you run it on all servers.

"When the process account for the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service (SPAdmin) is disabled (necessary in some installations for security reasons), the execadmsvcjobs operation must be run on all computers to perform provisioning and other administrative tasks that would ordinarily happen by using the Windows SharePoint Services Timer service (SPTimer)."

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262783(office.12).aspx